# multiplicity relationship of hashset and hashmap

Tags: java

I am confused about the multiplicity relationship of the two hash collections,

From what I see from another post here,

HashSet is a set, e.g. {1,2,3,4,5}

HashMap is a key -> value (key to value) map, e.g. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 1}

This looks like hashset is 1 unique ID tied to a set of data, eg. 1 2 3 4 5. which looks like a one-to-many relationship to me

And hashMap is 1 key to 1 value which is one-to-one relationship

And after googling to confirm my doubts, I ended up more confused.
From this post, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

It shows hashset used in both one to many and many to many relationship,
there are post that shows hashmap used in both too.

Can HashSet and HashMap be used in both One-To-Many and Many-To-Many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about the actual way they are intended to use, no!
For a relationship A->B

However, when I need to create 'One to Many' relationships, I resort to

```
 HashMap<A,HashSet<B>>
```

Doing this does enforce a unique constraint on the source of the relationship. To avoid that, one can reverse Map it using a HashMap

```
 HashMap<B,A>
```

In Many to Many relationships, there is no one unique key that can be used to access a pair of elements. So that basically means that the entire dataset is just a list of data pairs.

```
 List<{A,HashSet<B>}>
```

Where the WrapperObject has attributes identifier,HashSet<>.
Here the identifier is not necessarily unique.

If you are using the @ManyToMany annotation, Spring/Ebean are using this internally and you don't have to worry about representing the mapping as it is visible in the examples in the post. You need to set your mapping from the perspective of a single instance.

The entire array of instances is handled automatically for you.

Comment: Hi, few questions, 1) For the one-to-many relationship with the mixture of both hashs collections, how does this compare to just using hashset? As the input is still 1 unique identifier and output is still a set which cannot have duplicates. and 2) for the many to many using a list of wrapperobjects, it looks the same as a hashmap to me. as it is a list of key and values which sounds like a hashmap